# How to solve "bash: ls: command not found"

Tags: linux, bash

I did something wrong with **PATH**, so currently if I type `ls` command I get:

```
bash: ls: command not found
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I think after this command I get the errors : PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

Comment: That command shouldn't do it exactly as given there, but if it were typo'd, that's an explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Restore `$PATH`. The easiest way to do this is to close the current shell and open a new one (assuming you didn't futz with the shell startup files and this is why it's broken).